java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with GStreamer
I’m trying to use GStreamer with Java in a NetBeans project on Fedora 40. I've added the gstreamer-java-1.6.jar to my Libraries in NetBeans, but I'm encountering the following error when I run my code:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'gst_date_get_type': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined symbol: gst_date_get_type
at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:208)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:536)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:513)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:499)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:199)
at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.gst_date_get_type(Unknown Source)
at org.gstreamer.glib.GDate.<clinit>(GDate.java:40)
at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:300)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:140)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:145)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireOverrideFieldAccessor(Field.java:1200)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getOverrideFieldAccessor(Field.java:1169)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:444)
at org.gstreamer.Gst.getField(Gst.java:447)
at org.gstreamer.Gst.registerClass(Gst.java:460)
at org.gstreamer.Gst.loadAllClasses(Gst.java:471)
at org.gstreamer.Gst.init(Gst.java:338)
at app.VideoConference.<init>(VideoConference.java:50)
at app.Main.main(Main.java:29)

Do anybody have any solution for this? I have already installed GStreamer development package with sudo dnf install gstreamer1-devel

Make sure that the version of the native libraries you installed is compatible with the version of GStreamer you're using by studying the relevant documentation

See comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905922/gstreamer-java-application-receives-jna-access-error
